# Dataset variables are not accessible in in Table columns but are accessible in text fields created in Table column

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Steps to reproduce issue.

1. Create a new Data set
2. Create a variable in Data Set and assign it to some value
3. Create a JR Table and assign the created data set to the table.
4. Right click a column in Table Footer from Left Panel and add a cell.
5. Now Just click the column and on the right you will see "Column Print When" in the properties section, here add an expression to print only when the created variable to the Data Set is not empty.
6. Compile the report, error is thrown as "Variable Not found", But the variable is available in Data set. The same this works when a text field is added to the cell and an expression to print only when the created Data Set variable is not null.

Note :This question already asked in [Jasper community](http://community.jaspersoft.com/ireport-designer/issues/3177)

Comment: I had similar issue in one of my JRXML and my observation is print when expression only takes fields and variables from main data set not sub dataset. Which is why you have to think some other alternative to solve that problem.

Comment: @Fahad did you have any Solution for this.